# Adding a dev container from configuration files is stuck. (Dev container extension)

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

- VSCode Version: 1.76.0
- Local OS Version: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 64-bit
- Logs: No logs or notification appear

Steps:

1. Open a new vitesse project
2. Click on "Open a remote window" button
3. Click on :  Add dev container configuration files
4. Click on ; From predefined container configuration definition
5. Select : NodeJS + TypeScript
6. **Select node version is stuck and does not go to the next step**

**I can search for different node versions, but when i try to select one it does not work, i pressed Enter , Ctrl + Enter, Shit + Enter but im still stuck**

I Reinstalled the extension and also switched to the pre-release version but the problem is still their

[image: Screenshot from 2023-03-14 12-12-47]

It's just stuck at this point.

Comment: Saw you already opened an issue in their github, so now you can just wait. In the meantime, create your .devcontainer folder and config file manually, according to their node example https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-try-node

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/issues/1727#issuecomment-1468192617 this also works

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Figured out that you have to **login to GitHub Container registry** to be able to pull certain images. Now it is working fine for me.

You can follow the instructions in the official docs here -> https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry#authenticating-to-the-container-registry

Set the `GITHUB_TOKEN` env variable and then login `docker login ghcr.io`, enter your user name and token if prompted.